# Pulling code in local repository for a bitnami launched image

Tags: git, repository, google-compute-engine, bitnami, google-cloud-platform

I have launched a image for PrestaShop application from Bitnami in a Google Cloud Compute instance. Now I want to create a copy of source code on Cloud in local machine to make some changes and then push to it again, but not able to pull the source code in a local repository.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me where is your repository or your original code is located ? It is in GIT, Bit Bucket or on Google Cloud repository. Just go through the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/tools/repo/cloud-repositories) it will help you in configuring the cloud repositories.

Comment: I don't have anything in GIT or BitBucket, so it must be in Google Cloud repository. But when ever I click on Browse in Source Code in my project in Google Developers Console it shows "Some resources failed to load" error, and I am not able to see any code.

Comment: @Kushal: When you click the Browse in Source Code, on the right side you will find three option to push or clone the code on cloud repository. So select the third option "Clone your Cloud Repository to a local GIT repository" then select the instruction as given in that page. After that copy the source code to the robotics-test123/default director which is created in the previous step.

Comment: I have followed those steps and a empty repository was created at my machine without any source code. I want to pull source code on cloud image to my local machine.

Comment: @Kushal: The source code is not automatically available on Cloud Repository. You have to push the code from the local machine. However you can download your code from your application using the command  "appcfg.py download_app -A <your_app_id> -V <your_app_version> <output-dir>" given in the document [1]
[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Python_Downloading_source_code

Comment: I think it will help you.